# MySQL: select total stock en categoría

Tags: mysql

tengo una pregunta sencilla que espero que me podáis ayudar. Tengo varias tablas que gestionan productos, de ellas 2 tienen estos campos:

- t_categoria_producto: id_categoria, id_producto
- t_stock: id_producto, id_atributo, cantidad

Breve aclaración: Un producto puede estar asignado a varias categorías (para eso la tabla: t_categoria_producto). Y t_stock tiene como clave primaria: id_producto, id_atributo; por ejemplo, un producto puede ser un zapato y el atributo una talla, cada zapato y talla tiene una cantidad de stock.

**Necesito simplemente saber cuantos productos tiene una categoría pasando el id_categoria.**

Imagino que tengo que unir 2 sentencias. Por un lado hacer un SUM(cantidad) de t_stock (para obtener el stock de cada producto), y por otro lado sumar todos esos resultados habiendo seleccionado únicamente los productos de la categoría X. Aun que no es una consulta compleja, no he logrado todavía que la consulta me funcione.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda!

Comment: En estos casos se requiere ver la estructura de las tablas, la cual se puede obtener fácilmente mediante: `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre-de-la-tabla`. Y se requiere también un ejemplo mínimo de cómo existen los datos en cada tabla y del resultado esperado. [Puedes editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/170625/edit) para agregar esa información, si lo consideras oportuno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Más o menos ya lo has explicado en tu pregunta:

```
SELECT  c.id_categoria,
    SUM(s.cantidad)
    FROM t_stock s
    INNER JOIN t_categoria_producto c
        ON c.id_producto = s.id_producto
    WHERE c.id_categoria = <categoria a buscar>
    GROUP BY c.id_categoria
```

- `JOIN` entre el stock y las categorías por el `id_producto`
- Agrupamos por `id_categoria` y sumamos `s.cantidad`

Comment: Gracias Patricio funciona perfecto. Gran aporte!

Answer (score 0):

Voy a contestarte utilizando una [subconsulta](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-2017) ya que me parece lo óptimo.

```
(SELECT id_producto FROM t_categoria_producto WHERE id_categoria = 'valor')
--Recuperamos productos por categoría.
```

Y ahora la consulta "padre" usando la anterior consulta:
Con las cantidades por articulo y y atributo ya sumadas, ahora vamos a sumar todos esos resultados

```
SELECT SUM(CANTIDAD) AS TOTAL_ARTICULOS_POR_CATEGORIA
 FROM(
     SELECT id_producto, id_atributo, SUM(cantidad) AS CANTIDAD
      FROM t_stock stock
            --                   ↓ Articulos por categoría ↓
      WHERE stock.id_producto IN(SELECT id_producto 
                                 FROM t_categoria_producto 
                                 WHERE id_categoria = 'valor')
            --↓ Agrupamos por articulo y atributos ↓
      GROUP BY stock.id_producto, stock.id_atributo
  )
```

Comment: Gracias rencinas! en cuanto lo pueda probar te cuento ;)

Comment: Funciona muy bien, gracias rencinas!

Comment: @Valle En ese caso te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como respuesta correcta. Por dos motivos: Para que la siguiente persona que tenga una duda como la tuya, sepa que mi respuesta ha solucionado tu problema y tan solo tenga que adaptar el código a su caso en concreto. Y el segundo, la reputación, ya que nunca vienen mal unos puntos extra ;)